# Retrieve the code/reason from a close message

Tags: websocket++

I would like to retrieve the code and reason from a close message. I have registered a handler with `set_close_handler`, but that doesn't get a payload. Separately, I have found `websocketpp::close::extract_code` and `websocketpp::close::extract_reason` which take a payload and return the relevant pieces. Is the close payload stored somewhere? Are the last code/reason available in the `connection_ptr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection object has two accessor methods for this purpose:

```
close::status::value get_remote_close_code() const;
std::string const & get_remote_close_reason() const;
```

The on_close method is called with a connection_hdl, so you need to call get_con_from_hdl() to obtain a pointer to the connection. Here's an example:

```
void chat_server::on_close(connection_hdl hdl) {
    try {
        server::connection_ptr cp = m_server.get_con_from_hdl(hdl);
        websocketpp::close::status::value ccode = cp->get_remote_close_code();
        std::cout << "Closed connection. code " << ccode << " ["
            << cp->get_remote_close_reason() << "]" << std::endl;
    } catch (const websocketpp::lib::error_code& e) {
        std::cout << __func__ << " failed because: " << e << "(" << e.message() << ")"
             << std::endl;
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```